# What is the correct way to connect galvinized holding tank to a copper/brass fitting?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture

We have a galvanized holding tank in our well system.

I am going to re-plumb the entire thing to go to the largest diameter pipe it will accommodate which is 1 1/2 but the largest other plumbing fixtures will accommodate is 1 inch so I will have to reduce down from 1 1/2 to 1 inch at the tank.

I know I can't mix galvanized and brass or copper fittings together without a dielectric fitting. The problem I am running into is I can't seem to find a 1 1/2 to 1 inch dielectric fitting that I can then connect pex to.

It seems there are a few metal options I can find that are threaded at 1 1/2 inches down to 1 inch in the first place. So I am wondering if can I use a PVC threaded 1 1/2-inch threaded coupling, maybe find one with a reducer in it down to 1 inch, else get a reducer bushing down to 1 inch threaded and then connect the brass/copper pex fitting?

Is that enough non-contact between the metals to keep if from prematurely failing? What other options might I have?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use a galvanized reducing coupling and then a plastic adapter like https://www.supplyhouse.com/Uponor-Wirsbo-Q4621010-1-ProPEX-EP-Male-Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is no metal to metal contact, you won't get dielectric corrosion.  There are a lot of combinations you could use with PVC; any combination that ends up fitting the two pipes should be fine.